# Getting NullPointerExection error while creating a text file for an Agent in AnyLogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, agent

I have created an agent and  then I put a text file from the Connectivity pallet into that Agent model. As soon as I run the simulation it is displaying NullPointerException error. In the console it says Unknown Source. Although I have created that file prior to this and put the location of that  file from the properties pallet. I am using AnyLogic 7 pro.

1. [Error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMKit.png)
2. log :

   Error during model startup:
   NullPointerException
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.xj.anylogic.engine.Agent.getPresentation(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.engine.connectivity.TextFile.(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.engine.connectivity.TextFile.(Unknown Source)
   at warehouse.Worker.(Worker.java:71)
   at warehouse.Main._unloadingPerson_newUnit_xjal(Main.java:5246)
   at warehouse.Main.access$6(Main.java:5244)
   at warehouse.Main$7.newUnit(Main.java:1773)
   at com.xj.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool$b.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool.X(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool.onStartup(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool.start(Unknown Source)
   at warehouse.Main.start(Main.java:12747)
   at com.xj.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.xj.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
   at warehouse.Simulation.executeShapeControlAction(Simulation.java:127)
3. [Properties window of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAwAf.png)

I  don't know what I am doing wrong.
**Note :** This error doesn't happen when I put the same text file in the Main Agent model.

**Update :** I found a workaround. I linked the agent with the Main agent and then put the file in the Main agent. After  that I called that file from the agent function. To my understanding I think except the main agent other agents can't create a connectivity object. I am not  sure though.

Comment: Please don't add notes as comment but [edit] your question. Also don't post images of text but post the text itself (formatted to be readable of course). Links to read: [ask], https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you indicate that it is working when the same text file is placed on main, it might be the case that the agent gets created before the agent has access to the file...

Here are a few options and checks

Check 1: Ensure the file is accessible in the Resource section of the project under the data folder. It should not be greyed out and have a green dot on the left.

[image]

Check 2: There should also be a green dot next to the filename in the file object inside the agent where you placed it.

[image]

Alternative 1: Use a parameter inside the agent to pass the text file that exists on main to the agent to use it

[image]

[image]

Alternative 2: If your agent lives on main you can access the text file on main directly from the agent.

[image]

Note:
I don't think it is wise to have every agent access exactly the same text file from within themselves. It is better that they all access the same file object

Comment: Thank you so much !! Alternative 1 and 2 worked for me. I am using AnyLogic version 7 which doesn't come with a built in database and resource folder in  the directory. So couldn't check Check 1 and 2.